# How to manage state of selected items in a list without re-rendering entire list in React

Tags: reactjs, state-management

I have a list of about 50-100 items that are selectable and need to be tracked between pages in my application. I created a context to track those selected items between pages, a component that renders the list, and a component for each item in the list. Because of the length of the list, the responsiveness is slow when an item is selected and the entire array re-renders. I understand that since the parent context is updating state, the child list is re-rendering, causing the slow reaction. How can I manage the state of selected items in a list while only updating the list item component instead of the entire array? I am using react-query to populate the list.

Context managing the selected items

```js
const Context = createContext({
  items: [],
  setItems: () => null,
});

export const ContextProvider = (props: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const { children } = props;

  const [items, setItems] = useState<number[]>([]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        items,
        setItems,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export const useExampleContext = () => useContext(Context);
```

List component for the items

```js
const ItemList = () => {
  const itemsQuery = useQuery({
    queryFn: () => getItems(),
    queryKey: ['items']
  });

  if (itemsQuery.isFetching) return (
    <Box>
      <Spinner />
    </Box>
  );

  if (itemsQuery.error) return (
    <Box>
      <Heading>Error loading items</Heading>
    </Box>
  );

  return (
    <Center>
      <Heading size="xl">
        Items
      </Heading>
      <ScrollView maxHeight="$2/3">
        {itemsQuery.data.items.map((i) => (
          <Item key={i.id} i={i} />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </Center>
  );
};
```

List Item component

```js
const Item = ({ i }) => {
  const { items, setItems } = useExampleContext();

  const handleSelection = (itemId: number) => {
    if (items.includes(itemId)) {
      setItems(items.filter((i) => i !== itemId));
      return;
    }

    setItems((prev) => [...prev, itemId]);
  };

  return (
    <Box m="$2">
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          handleSelection(i.id);
        }}
      >
        <CircleIcon
          color={items.includes(i.id) ? '$tertiary500' : 'white'}
        />
        <ButtonText color="$secondary500" size="xl">{i.label}</ButtonText>
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
```